# Stripe exception is not working .giving laravel errors instead of exception errors

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments

I am using stripe payment gateway in my project. I am trying to display exception errors when a user entered expired card number. but instead of showing me error of exception it shows me laravel error. 
Note: it is not working with any kind of exception not only expired card number.

I am using the exception provided by Stripe.

```php
public function recharge(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'amount'        => 'required',

    ]);

    $amount = $request->input('amount');
    \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey('key_here');

    try {
        $token  = $_POST['stripeToken'];

        $charge = \Stripe\Charge::create([
            'amount'      => $amount * 100,
            'currency'    => 'usd',
            'description' => 'Example charge',
            'source'      => $token,
        ]);

        $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $user->deposit($amount);

        Session::flash('success', 'Your Wallet is recharged!');
        return back();
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Card $e) {
        // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Error\Card will be caught
        $body = $e->getJsonBody();
        $err  = $body['error'];

        print('Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . "\n");
        print('Type is:' . $err['type'] . "\n");
        print('Code is:' . $err['code'] . "\n");

        // param is '' in this case
        print('Param is:' . $err['param'] . "\n");
        print('Message is:' . $err['message'] . "\n");
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\InvalidRequest $e) {
        return "error";
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Authentication $e) {
        return "error";
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\ApiConnection $e) {
        // Network communication with Stripe failed
        return "error";
    } catch (\Stripe\Error\Base $e) {

        return "error";
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

I want to display the error defined by me in the catch block.

Comment: what "Laravel error"?

Comment: i mean default error of laravel . Stripe \ Exception \ CardException
Your card has expired.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are not catching the `Stripe\Exception\CardException` exception. You are probably not actually catching `Exception` either, unless you have aliased `Exception` at the top of your file.

Add `use Exception;` before the class declaration at the top or adjust `Exception` in the catch to `\Exception`.

Looks like the newer version of `stripe-php` library throws Exceptions from `Stripe\Exception` and no longer has a namespace `Stripe\Error` FYI.

[Stripe API Reference - Handling Errors](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling)

Answer (score 7):

Stripe API Document on [errors](https://stripe.com/docs/api/errors/handling?lang=php) has pretty much everything we can get. here is the Code block you can put while using stripe library.

```
try {
  // Use Stripe's library to make requests...
} catch(\Stripe\Exception\CardException $e) {
  // Since it's a decline, \Stripe\Exception\CardException will be caught
  echo 'Status is:' . $e->getHttpStatus() . '\n';
  echo 'Type is:' . $e->getError()->type . '\n';
  echo 'Code is:' . $e->getError()->code . '\n';
  // param is '' in this case
  echo 'Param is:' . $e->getError()->param . '\n';
  echo 'Message is:' . $e->getError()->message . '\n';
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\RateLimitException $e) {
  // Too many requests made to the API too quickly
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\InvalidRequestException $e) {
  // Invalid parameters were supplied to Stripe's API
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\AuthenticationException $e) {
  // Authentication with Stripe's API failed
  // (maybe you changed API keys recently)
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiConnectionException $e) {
  // Network communication with Stripe failed
} catch (\Stripe\Exception\ApiErrorException $e) {
  // Display a very generic error to the user, and maybe send
  // yourself an email
} catch (Exception $e) {
  // Something else happened, completely unrelated to Stripe
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed by including `use Exception;`